# php file will not list rows in data base table

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a table in a data base with this schema:

```
"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `call_log` (
`clid` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`medid1` int(6) NOT NULL,
`medid2` int(6) NOT NULL,
`patid` int(6) NOT NULL,
`dcode` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`acode` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
`transp` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
`facid` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
`date1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`time1` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`reg-date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`clid`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;
```

am using this file to list the table: NOTE# the PHPconn.php contains the log in info for db

```
<? 

include("PHPConn.php");


mysql_connect ("$host", "$user","$password")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("$database");

echo "<table border=1 >"; 
echo "<tr>"; 
echo "<td><b>Clid</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Medid1</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Medid2</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Patid</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Dcode</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Acode</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Transp</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Facid</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Date1</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Time1</b></td>"; 
echo "<td><b>Reg-date</b></td>"; 
echo "</tr>"; 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `call_log`") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } 
echo "<tr>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['clid']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['medid1']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['medid2']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['patid']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['dcode']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['acode']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['transp']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['facid']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['date1']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['time1']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'>" . nl2br( $row['reg-date']) . "</td>";  
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?id={$row['id']}>Edit</a></td><td><a       href=delete.php?id={$row['id']}>Delete</a></td> "; 
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>"; 
echo "<a href=new.php>New Row</a>"; 
?>
```

When i call the filel I get this error"

```
"; echo ""; echo "Clid"; echo "Medid1"; echo "Medid2"; echo "Patid"; echo "Dcode"; echo "Acode"; echo "Transp"; echo "Facid"; echo "Date1"; echo "Time1"; echo "Reg-date"; echo ""; $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `call_log`") or trigger_error(mysql_error()); while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ foreach($row AS $key => $value) { $row[$key] = stripslashes($value); } echo ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['clid']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['medid1']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['medid2']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['patid']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['dcode']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['acode']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['transp']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['facid']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['date1']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['time1']) . ""; echo "" . nl2br( $row['reg-date']) . ""; echo "EditDelete "; echo ""; } echo ""; echo "New Row"; ?>
```

I can add data to the table via a form without issue.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: mysql_query has been deprecated please use mysqli or PDO

Comment: I have added Niels revision now error is sililar to lat error except table frames are shown.  All I would like to do is list all rows in the table.   Thank you all your helping

Comment: I solved this issue,  I do not under stand why but I found out the <? tag to start the PHP script must begin with <?PHP  and not <? for this file.  I made that change tho original code and it works fine

Comment: @user2326872 Your table as defined to us in your question does not have an 'id' fields defined.

Comment: @user2326872  If you want to use the short_tag form <?=$xxx?> you have to turn short open tags ON, Use wampmanager->PHP->PHP Settings->short open tags.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious problem here, you dont actually have a item in the array called 'id'

```
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?id={$row['id']}>Edit</a>
```

Should this not be

```
echo "<td valign='top'><a href=edit.php?id={$row['clid']}>Edit</a>
```

Also why bother with the foreach loop, why not just do this

echo "" . nl2br( stripslashes( $row['clid']) ) . "";

Comment: I solved this issue,  I do not under stand why but I found out the <? tag to start the PHP script must begin with <?PHP  and not <? for this file.  I made that change tho original code and it works fine

Comment: @ Riggs   the  'id' identifies the row in sql.  the 'clid' identifies the row for us humans.   I could be wrong but thats how I under stand it.  All I did was just change the <? to <?PHP works fine.